# NullPointerException with findViewById in variable definition

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have read the immensely popular thread about Null Point Exceptions but I'm still confused about why I'm getting the error. I am attempting to make sure some EditText's are filled out. I have tried it in the onCreate method and it still doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize if this is some stupid question.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener { 

EditText scoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSN);
EditText teamNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTN);
EditText matchNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMatchNumber);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fieldsOK) {
                openActivity2();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You have Missing Forms");
            }
        }
    });
}


private boolean validate(EditText[] fields){
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        EditText currentField = fields[i];
        if(currentField.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean fieldsOK = validate(new EditText[] { scoutName, teamNumber, matchNumber });
```

error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scoutingapp3250/com.example.scoutingapp3250.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

The error comes on the the scoutName on above the onCreate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `findViewById` after calling `setContentView` in `onCreate`

Comment: i keep getting the variable names as never used even though its used in the fieldsOK array. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what `fieldsOkay` is, because I can't see your code.

Comment: its in the question at the bottom of the first coded stack

Comment: Psychic debugging: you probably are initializing them in onCreate, but since that happens after `fieldsOK` is initialized, it's telling you that `fieldsOK` is seeing the old, uninitialized, `null` values.  You need to check the values after setting them.

Comment: could it have to do with the fact that those EditTexts are technically null at the startup of the activity. The things im referencing are unfilled on activity start as I am making a questionnaire.

Comment: They're null because they're not set until `onCreate`.  It doesn't matter though because `fieldsOK` is pointless as written - it is only called once at the start.  You need to make it a method.

Comment: whats wrong with the fieldsOK. Its a variable that uses the method validate to decide whether its true or false that EditText's are empty. Any clarification would be awesome

Comment: It's only called before the user has a chance to fill out the EditTexts - in fact, it's called before the variables holding the EditTexts are even initialized

Comment: its outside my onCreate so doesnt that mean it just runs in the backround constantly while that activity is open?

Comment: No.  You may want to read more about [initializing fields in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).